# SharePoint Migration

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, network-drive

I am trying to move some shared network drives from our domain controller over to our SharePoint site, I figured doing this manually would be fine but due to some new limitations that I've discovered, I may be over my head.

What is the quickest and most efficient way to move 46GB(this is just one shared folder btw) worth of files and folders to SharePoint?

I am researching solutions, however, as I am reaching close to a dead line I figured I'd ask.

And just a quick idea that came to me just now, if I were to install OneDrive to the domain controller and sync with the respective sites, would that work as a good solution to move these large amounts of files?

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint Migration Tool. It is a free tool from Microsoft and does a very decent job with excellent logs to verify each file migration status.
It uses SharePoint Migration API to perform super fast migration. For simple file share migration, It is one of my favourite tool. It is very easy to use.

Comment: thank you!! i will set this up and give it a try.

I'll keep you posted on updates

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark it as answer, if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, SharePoint Migration Tool is a good choice.

[Download and install the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)

Then create a migration task with SPMT and after that you could Monitor and Report migration tasks.

Reference:
[SPMT-supported features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/what-is-supported-spmt)

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that you could use is [Migration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-get-started)

Microsoft Docs have documented a complete review of the Tool and there's a step by step guide for you to follow in order to complete the Migration.

1. [Setup Migration Manager agents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-setup-clients)
2. [Create a migration task with Migration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-how-to-use)
3. [Monitor and report in Migration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/mm-reports)

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll keep this tool in mind in case the other tool doesn't work as expected